# Independence is preserved under set-theoretic restriction to pre-image.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent real (Borel-measurable) random variables, and define $\Omega_X:= X^{-1}(U)$ and $\Omega_Y:=Y^{-1}(U)$ (for some open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$).

Can we infer that the random variables $X\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\Omega_X}$ and $Y\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\Omega_Y}$ are independent?

Comment: In other words you are asking if $X 1_{\{X \in U\}}$ and $Y1_{\{Y \in U\}}$ are independent?

Comment: @Michael Yes...

Comment: We have $g(X) = X 1_{\{X \in U\}}$ and $h(Y) = Y 1_{\{Y \in U\}}$.  These are measurable functions $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Comment: Oh great, thanks a lot! @Michael

Comment: You are welcome.  If you like, you can write up a short answer to your own question and give it "best answer," which is standard practice if you solve a problem based on hints.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael remarked in the comments, the answer to this question is obviously yes.

*Proof:* As $X\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\Omega_X} = f(X)$ and $Y\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\Omega_Y} = f(Y)$ for the (Borel-)measurable function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(z):= z\cdot\mathbb{1}_U(z)$, the assertion follows by the fact that independence is preserved by measurable transformations.